# Ideal Screen Sharing Conditions

Tags: macos, windows, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I realise what I am about to ask could be considered impossible to answer but maybe a discussion might be helpful to other people.

I am trying to use Screen Sharing (OS X 10.7.5) to control a Windows 7 PC at a remote site which is running Ultra VNC. I keep getting 'system not responding' errors in the applications I am using on the remote PC, even though when I am onsite I never get them. It's making things pretty hard work as I'm essentially locked out of the application for anywhere between 10-30 seconds at a time. I'm pretty certain that something to do with VNC is causing the problems and have had the same when using Chicken of the VNC on my Mac as well, does anyone have some recommendations as to what to do in this scenario?

Comment: For instance does the speed of my connection have any influence on how fast VNC will work on the remote PC? I am currently uploading an offsite back up, could that be affecting things?

Comment: VNC is generally not considered to be a very fast protocol either. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Try the TeamViewer application for remote control.

I use it daily across the ocean and across the platforms (Windows/Mac) and it works fine.

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx

Comment: I'm getting the same errors when I use Team Viewer. I wonder if this is a problem related directly to the software I am trying to use on the remote computer, it's called GMG ColorProof.

Comment: Well, I would say you are on the right track. Now that have verified it is not the remote control software you are using. it must be the program on the remote computer. Unfortunately I am not familiar with GMG ColorProof.

Comment: I can vouch for TeamViewer too. It works quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done much with remote sites—mostly LAN-based stuff—but if I'm going to control a Windows machine from my Mac, I use RDP, since it's the native solution for Windows and Microsoft provides a free client.

http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client

It's my understanding that in order to use it remotely, you need to make sure you can reach port 3389 on the machine to be controlled.  Of course, you should be doing this over a VPN or similar.

Comment: That all sounds logical zigg, I'll take a look!

Comment: Hmm, the latest version says that it isn't intended for use with Lion (I am running Lion) but the earlier version doesn't support Windows 7! I'm going to see if the latest version will actually run under Lion.

Comment: Good luck.  I honestly cannot recall whether I was successfully using it with Lion.

Comment: Hey @zigg, would you explain the reasoning behind your closing statement: _"Of course, you should be doing this over a VPN or similar."_? Cheers. n_n

Comment: @tjt263 For security—you should practice defense-in-depth by not exposing RDP directly to the public Internet. Using a VPN defends against both unauthorized access to the service and encrypts all traffic between your computer and the remotely-accessed computer.